# How can I prevent Facebook from gathering data when using it on Linux?

Tags: privacy, facebook

I know that Facebook tries to collect data when browsing, even when you're not browsing Facebook itself.

I dislike this behaviour and therefore would like to prevent Facebook from gathering as much data as possible from me.

On the other hand, I don't want to completely ditch Facebook and keep as much of the website's functions as possible. At this point, I'm browsing Facebook daily.

I'm browsing Facebook with Firefox, running on Ubuntu 17.04.

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a separate browser with a different fingerprint from your main browser. For example, if you're using Linux with Chrome for your daily browsing, use Windows and Internet Explorer for Facebook (in a VM for example). In the VM set a slightly lower screen resolution so they can't track you on that either.

Finally in your daily browser use an extension such as uBlock Origin with an aggressive filter list (tracking lists and "anti third-party social") to prevent your daily browser from loading Facebook's tracking scripts such as the like buttons.